# Convert equation from string in postgresql

Tags: regex, string, postgresql, equation

I am trying to write a query that takes in a string, where an equation in the form

```
x^3 + 0.0046x^2 - 0.159x +1.713
```

is expected. The equation is used to calculate new values in the output table from a list of existing values. Hence I will need to convert whatever the input equation string is into an equation that postgresql can process, e.g.

```
power(data.value,3) + 0.0046 * power(data.value,2) - 0.159 * data.value + 1.713
```

A few comforting constraints in this task are

1. The equation will always be in the form of a polynomial, e.g. sum(A_n * x^n)
2. The user will always use 'x' to represent the variable in the input equation

I have been pushing my queries into a string and executing it at the end, e.g.

```
_query TEXT;
SELECT 'select * from ' INTO _query;
SELECT _query || 'product.getlength( ' || min || ',' || max || ')' INTO _query;
RETURN QUERY EXECUTE _query;
```

Hence I know I only need to somehow

1. Replace the 'x''s to 'data.values'
2. Find all the places in the equation string where a number
   immediately precede a 'x', and add a '*'
3. Find all exponential operations (x^n) in the equation string and
   convert them to power(x,n)

This may very well be something very trivial for a lot of people, unfortunately postgresql is not my best skill and I have already spent way more time than I can afford to get this working. Any type of help is highly appreciated, cheers.

Comment: The good news for you is that this is not really postgresql. You need to take your string and process it with your favorite programming language. Then you can build a simple select query with it.

Comment: It would be much easier in other languages such as python, unfortunately if I was did not make it clear, I have to implement this process within a postgresql query function, which reads the string value from the db according to the input.......

Comment: What makes me think that this is a home work exercise?

Comment: I knew this question would give some people this very impression, the truth is that it would be easier if it really was homework, where it would be given a week in advance and I can spend all weekend cracking it. Rather it is part of a task to do at work, given at 9 am and to be done by noon, along with a million other things...

Comment: I am sorry to hear that but this is an extremely stupid requirement. Your best bet is to write a stored function with python but for that you would need the extension to be enabled. SQL simply isn't geared to handle complex string processing.

Comment: I do share a very similar opinion that postgresql is not the friendliest tool for this, because I think I spent less time when I first did something similar in python that I used to write this post.

With a whole page of functions on string manipulation:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-string.html

I think it is possible albeit possibly much more complicated than in other platforms. I just don't have time left to dig through this, and was hoping that and expert would appear and save my day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 9am-noon time frame is over, but here goes.

Every term of the polynomial has 4 elements:

1. Addition/subtraction modifier
2. Multiplier
3. Parameter, always `x` in your case
4. Power

The problem is that these elements are not always present. The first term has no addition element, although it could have a subtraction sign `-` which is then typically connected to the multiplier. Multipliers are only given when not equal to 1. The parameter is not present in the last term and neither is a power in the last two terms.

With optional capture groups in regular expression parsing you can sort out this mess and PostgreSQL has the handy [`regexp_matches()` function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP) for this:

```
SELECT * FROM
    regexp_matches('x^3 + 0.0046x^2 - 0.159x +1.713',
                   '\s*([+-]?)\s*([0-9.]*)(x?)\^?([0-9]*)', 'g') AS r (terms);
```

The regular expression says this:

- `\s*` Read 0 or more spaces.
- `([+-]?)` Capture 0 or 1 plus or minus sign.
- `\s*` Read 0 or more spaces.
- `([0-9.]*)` Capture a number consisting of digit and a decimal dot, if present.
- `(x?)` Capture the parameter `x`. This is necessary to differentiate between the last two terms, see query below.
- `\^?` Read the power symbol, if present. Must be escaped because `^` is the constraint character.
- `([0-9]*)` Capture an integer number, if present.

The `g` modifier repeats this process for every matching pattern in the string.

On your string this yields, in the form of string arrays:

```
|      terms      |
|-----------------|
| {'','',x,3}     |
| {+,0.0046,x,2}  |
| {-,0.159,x,''}  |
| {+,1.713,'',''} |
| {'','','',''}   |
```

(I have no idea why the last line with all empty strings comes out. Maybe a real expert can explain that.)

With this result, you can piece your query together:

```
SELECT id, sum(term)
FROM (
  SELECT id, 
         CASE WHEN terms[1] = '-' THEN -1
              WHEN terms[1] = '+' THEN 1
              WHEN terms[3] = 'x' THEN 1  -- If no x then NULL
         END *
         CASE terms[2] WHEN '' THEN 1. ELSE terms[2]::float
         END *
         value ^ CASE WHEN terms[3] = '' THEN 0 -- If no x then 0 (x^0)
                      WHEN terms[4] = '' THEN 1 -- If no power then 1 (x^1)
                      ELSE terms[4]::int
                 END AS term
  FROM data
  JOIN regexp_matches('x^3 + 0.0046x^2 - 0.159x +1.713',
                      '\s*([+-]?)\s*([0-9.]*)(x?)\^?([0-9]*)', 'g') AS r (terms) ON true
  ) sub
GROUP BY id         
ORDER BY id;
```

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/15062/1)

This assumes you have an `id` column to join on. If all you have is a `value` then you can still do it but you should then wrap the above query in a function that you feed the polynomial and the value. The power is assumed to be integral but you can easily turn that into a real number by adding a dot `.` to the regular expression and a `::float` cast instead of `::int` in the `CASE` statement. You can also support negative powers by adding another capture group to the regular expression and a case statement in the query, same as for the multiplier term; I leave this for your next weekend hackfest.

This query will also handle "odd" polynomials such as `-4.3x^3+     101.2   +         0.0046x^6 - 0.952x^7 +4x` just so long as the pattern described above is maintained.

Comment: Interesting solution (though I did not test it myself). The last  match represents the [end-of-data](https://regex101.com/r/eS8hN2/1) `$` (because all of your terms are optional -- you only use the `?` and `*` quantifiers). You can eliminate it with a [negative lookahead: `(?!$)`](https://regex101.com/r/eS8hN2/2).

Comment: @pozs The SQLfiddle is there so go right ahead and test it. Thanks for the negative lookahead, hadn't thought about that.

Comment: I don't think that regex is well-suited for these kind of tasks (just think of `--1` f.ex.: in real world, that usually means `+1`, but that substitution would be really painful to express in regex. Moreover the database engine (PostgreSQL) also doesn't fit well for parsing expressions. It can be done, and it might even work with certain circumstances (f.ex. validating input before inserting these expressions into the database), but these tasks just better suited for backend application layers between the user and the database.

Comment: @pozs I agree that PG is not well suited to this _kind_ of task, but the question makes it a _specific_ task (a simple one-parameter polynomial) and the answer certainly addresses what the OP asked for.

Comment: Thanks heaps for the input (my day is officially saved). It does exactly what I need and can certainly replace the dirty hack that I temporarily put in before the deadline.